# How to render children using the h() render function

Tags: vuejs3

I have created a component that renders a div programmatically using the h() function:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { h } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup () {
    return () => h('div', {}, 'This is a test');
  }
};
</script>
```

In the parent I insert the component, and also adding some child content:

```
 <Test>
      <p>Children!</p>
      <p>Children!</p>
 </Test>
```

The question is, how can I render those children in the Test component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`default`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) slot with [`Render Functions`](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html).

See [Rendering Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#rendering-slots).

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const test = {   
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () => h('div', {}, slots.default())
  }
}

const App = {
  components: { 
    test
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>  
  <test>
   <p>Children!</p>
   <p>Children!</p>
  </test>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```